# serializing an arrayList of objects in Android Project

Tags: android, listview, serialization, arraylist

I'm working on a proyect i have to handle in at the endo of the term (which in spain si within 10 days). I'm not able to serialize an arrayList of objects.
I have this class Curriculum and I create objects of this class and put them into an arrayList. They I serialize the arrayList (this happens in the VistaPrevia activity).

In the activity ListadoCV, I de-serialize the arrayList, an load a ListView with it.

If I create the objects manually in the ListadoCV activity, add them to an arrayList and then load the ListView with them, the ListView works fine. On the other side, when I de-serialize the arrayList serialized in the VistaPrevia activity in the ListadoCV activity, the ListView shows nothing at all.
This is what makes me think the problem is born when serializing.

I've spent more than 20 hours in the last 3 days trying to solve this, reading tutorials and forums, but can't figure out how to solve it. I had a java class I made last year to serialize that worked fine in java projects, but it doesn't seem to work here in android...

**Curriculum CLASS**

```
    package com.dam204.trabajoevaluacion;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class Curriculum implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1520731881414914436L;
/**
 * 
 */
// DATOS PERSONALES
String nombre;
String apellido1;
String apellido2;
String dni;
String email;
String direccion;
int cp;
String localidad;
String provincia;

// DATOS ACADÉMICOS
String titulacion;

// EXPERIENCIA LABORAL
String experiencia;

// IMAGEN
int logotipo;

public Curriculum(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2,
        String dni, String email, String direccion, int cp,
        String localidad, String provincia, String titulacion,
        String experiencia, int logotipo) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.email = email;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.cp = cp;
    this.localidad = localidad;
    this.provincia = provincia;
    this.titulacion = titulacion;
    this.experiencia = experiencia;
    this.logotipo = logotipo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido1() {
    return apellido1;
}

public void setApellido1(String apellido1) {
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
}

public String getApellido2() {
    return apellido2;
}

public void setApellido2(String apellido2) {
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
}

public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}

public void setDni(String dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public int getCp() {
    return cp;
}

public void setCp(int cp) {
    this.cp = cp;
}

public String getLocalidad() {
    return localidad;
}

public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
    this.localidad = localidad;
}

public String getProvincia() {
    return provincia;
}

public void setProvincia(String provincia) {
    this.provincia = provincia;
}

public String getTitulacion() {
    return titulacion;
}

public void setTitulacion(String titulacion) {
    this.titulacion = titulacion;
}

public String getExperiencia() {
    return experiencia;
}

public void setExperiencia(String experiencia) {
    this.experiencia = experiencia;
}

public int getLogotipo() {
    return logotipo;
}

public void setLogotipo(int logotipo) {
    this.logotipo = logotipo;
}


}
```

**GuardarCargarObjetos CLASS (serializing CLASS)**

```
    package com.dam204.trabajoevaluacion;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.io.OptionalDataException;
    import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;

    public class GuardarCargarObjetos {

static String filename = "CVsGuardados.dat";

public static void Serializa(Context context, ArrayList<Curriculum> a) {

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        //fos = context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(a);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Curriculum> Desserializa(Context context) {
    FileInputStream fin;
    ArrayList<Curriculum> afromfile = null;

    try {
        fin = context.openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        afromfile = (ArrayList<Curriculum>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return afromfile;

}

}
```

**ListadoCV ACTIVITY**

```
    package com.dam204.trabajoevaluacion;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class ListadoCV extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listadocv);

    // CREAMOS LA LISTA Y COMPROBAMOS SI EXISTE EL ARCHIVO, SI EXISTE LO
    // CARGAMOS

    ArrayList<Curriculum> curriculums = new ArrayList<Curriculum>();

    String filename = "CVsGuardados.dat";
    File fichero = new File(filename);
    if(fichero.exists()){
        curriculums = GuardarCargarObjetos.Desserializa(getApplicationContext());
    }


      /*String sFichero = "CVs_guardados.dat";
      File fichero = new File(sFichero);
      if (fichero.exists()) {

        try {
            curriculums = Serializador.cargarCVs();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          } */   


     /* curriculums.add(new Curriculum("pepe", "fernandez", "martinez",
      "53169968-v", "manuelcanadas@gmail.com", "sdgsdgsd", 234235,
      "sdfsdfd", "sdgsdgds", "sdfgsdgsdg", "dfgdfgdfgdf",
      android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));

      curriculums.add(new Curriculum("mario", "perez", "sanchez",
      "34546576-x", "madnufelcganhadjas@hotmail.com", "sdgsdgsd", 287656,
      "sdfsdfd", "sdgsdgds", "sdfgsdgsdg",
      "dfgdfhhtgdfbhfdhhttegbrtgdfgdf",
      android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));*/


    Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(ListadoCV.this, curriculums);
    setListAdapter(adaptador);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listado_cv, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

**VistaPrevia ACTIVITY**

```
    package com.dam204.trabajoevaluacion;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class VistaPrevia extends Activity {

TextView tv_titulo_previa, tv_nombre_completo, tv_dni, tv_email,
        tv_direccion, tv_cp, tv_localidad, tv_provincia, tv_titulacion,
        tv_experiencia;

String nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, email, direccion, localidad,
        provincia, titulacion, experiencia;
int cp;

String nombre_completo;

Button confirmar, reiniciar;

ArrayList<Curriculum> lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vistaprevia);

    // CREAMOS LA LISTA Y COMPROBAMOS SI EXISTE EL ARCHIVO, SI EXISTE LO
    // CARGAMOS
    /*lista = new ArrayList<Curriculum>();
    String sFichero = "CVs_guardados.dat";
    File fichero = new File(sFichero);
    if (fichero.exists()) {
        try {
            // lista1 = Serializador.cargarCVs();
            lista = Serializador.cargarCVs();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/
    lista = new ArrayList<Curriculum>();
    String filename = "CVsGuardados.dat";
    File fichero = new File(filename);
    if(fichero.exists()){
        lista = GuardarCargarObjetos.Desserializa(getApplicationContext());
    }

    // RECOGEMOS LOS DATOS ENVIADOS DESDE LA ACTIVIDAD ANTERIOR
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    nombre = extras.getString("nombre");
    apellido1 = extras.getString("apellido1");
    apellido2 = extras.getString("apellido2");
    dni = extras.getString("dni");
    email = extras.getString("email");
    direccion = extras.getString("direccion");
    cp = extras.getInt("cp");
    localidad = extras.getString("localidad");
    provincia = extras.getString("provincia");
    titulacion = extras.getString("titulacion");
    experiencia = extras.getString("experiencia");

    // ASIGNAMOS LOS DATOS RECIBIDOS DESDE LA ACTIVIDAD ANTERIOR A LOS
    // TextView DE ESTA ACTIVIDAD
    tv_titulo_previa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo_previa);
    tv_titulo_previa.setText("CV de " + nombre + " " + apellido1);

    tv_nombre_completo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre_completo);
    nombre_completo = apellido1 + " " + apellido2 + ", " + nombre;
    tv_nombre_completo.setText(nombre_completo);

    tv_dni = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dni);
    tv_dni.setText(dni);

    tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
    tv_email.setText(email);

    tv_direccion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_direccion);
    tv_direccion.setText(direccion);

    tv_cp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_cp);
    tv_cp.setText(Integer.toString(cp));

    tv_localidad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_localidad);
    tv_localidad.setText(localidad);

    tv_provincia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_provincia);
    tv_provincia.setText(provincia);

    tv_titulacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_titulacion);
    tv_titulacion.setText(titulacion);

    tv_experiencia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_experiencia);
    tv_experiencia.setText(experiencia);

    // LINKAMOS LOS BOTONES DEL XML CON EL JAVA
    confirmar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_confirmar);
    reiniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reiniciar);

    // BOTON CONFIRMAR
    confirmar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // implementar la creacion del objeto de la clase Curriculum
            // implementar que se añada el objeto a la lista
            // implementar la serializacion de la lista de objetos

            Curriculum nuevoCV = new Curriculum(nombre, apellido1,
                    apellido2, dni, email, direccion, cp, localidad,
                    provincia, titulacion, experiencia, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);

            // lista1.agregarCurriculum(nuevoCV);
            lista.add(nuevoCV);

            // Serializador.guardarCVs(lista1);
            //Serializador.guardarCVs(lista);
            GuardarCargarObjetos.Serializa(getApplicationContext(), lista);

            Intent intent = new Intent(VistaPrevia.this, Principal.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });

    // BOTON REINICIAR
    reiniciar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(VistaPrevia.this, CrearCV.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vista_previa, menu);
    return true;
}

// SI LA ACTIVIDAD ENTRA EN PAUSA (NOS MOVEMOS A OTRA ACTIVIDAD), LA
// ACTIVIDAD ACTUAL SE CIERRA
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

    }
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions logged in LogCat? If so, which? Does `fichero.exists()` return `true`? I suspect it doesn't, because otherwise you'd be seeing a NPE. I suggest you step through the code with a debugger attached. That should help you narrow down the origin of the problem without too much effort.

Comment: when I comment that if(fichero.exists()){} line, happens what you just said. It throws a NPE...

Comment: why does it give a NPE? i'm quite noob :(

Comment: That means serializing to a file probably failed in the first place. Something bad happens in the `try` block. The exact exception will give you more details on *what* is going wrong. Make sure you've requested all the right permissions in the manifest, and, as suggested before, use a debugger to step through your code on a line-by-line basis to pinpoint the origin.

Comment: thamks for answering me in the first place. I thought I only had to use permissions in order to store in external SD. I've searched through the permissions list but can't figure out wichi one is for internal storing. I've been also looking at some debugging videos in youtube, I'll try this today. Thanks again!

Comment: ok, i inserted the following permissions, but still can't get it to work... I debugged the app and the serialization seems to work... damn...

Comment: now, the problem were the stupid  ´String filename = "CVsGuardados.dat";
    File fichero = new File(filename);
    if(fichero.exists()){
        curriculums = GuardarCargarObjetos.Desserializa(getApplicationContext());
    }´ from ListadoCV activity and the stupid ´String filename = "CVsGuardados.dat";
    File fichero = new File(filename);
    if(fichero.exists()){
        lista = GuardarCargarObjetos.Desserializa(getApplicationContext());
    }´ from VistaPrevia activity. when I comment them everything works fine.

Comment: The problem now is how do I check if the file ´CVsGuardados.dat´ already exists? I thought that was the right way to do it...

Comment: solved :) THANKS SO MUCH MH

Comment: If this isn't worth a self-learners badge... :) You're most welcome, although all I did was point you in a direction. You did all the hard work yourself. Happy coding!